# The number of solution of a Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

If we fixe $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I was wondring if there is an estimation of the number of the integer solutions of the equation :
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=n^3 $$
where $x_i>0$ for all $i=1,\cdots,n$.

In fact we can notice that if $x_i=n$ for all $i=1,\cdots,n$ is a solution and when we try to solve this equation for n given we find that:

- for $n=1$  there is $1$ solution $(1)$
- for $n=2$  there is $1$ solution $(2,2)$
- for $n=3$  there is $2$ solutions $(3,3,3)$ and $(5,1,1)$
- for $n=4$  there is $1$ solution $(4,4,4,4)$
- $\cdots$

**Question:** Is there any known formula or estimation for the number of solutions?

Comment: unlikely to be any nice expression when demanding $x_i > 0.$ Representation counts for quadratic forms are done with no such restriction.

Comment: You might get some estimates with Minkowski's inequality (see Geometry of Numbers).

Comment: Do you mean that there is a formula for $r(s,n)$ the number of the representation of n as sum of s squares , where can i find it because i know just some cases s=4 , s=2 thanks

Comment: It would be worth adding the $2$ solutions in the case of $n=3$ (I only found $1+1+25=27$).

Comment: @Joffan: Thanks. BTW, I see no good reason to down-vote this question (not saying it was you).

Comment: @WillJagy : Is there a formula for $r(s,n)$ the number of representation of $n$ as a sum of $s$ squares? thanks

Comment: I get $a_5=9$ - (11,1,1,1,1),(10,4,2,2,1),(9,5,3,3,1),(8,7,2,2,2),(7,7,5,1,1),(7,7,3,3,3),(7,5,5,5,1),(6,6,6,4,1),(5,5,5,5,5) - any variants?

Comment: I found this http://math.uga.edu/~lyall/Learning/SumsSquares.pdf but i can't use it in my case because the number of variables depends on $n$

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Representations-Integers-as-Sums-Squares/dp/1461385687